# Can we separate Toeplitz matrices for negative and positive eigenvalues? 

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Consider a Toeplitz matrix T which has both positive and negative eigenvalues. Can we prove that there exist two Toeplitz matrix T1 and T2 such that T1+T2=T and T1 has only one positive Eigenvalues and T2 has only negative Eigenvalues? Any reply would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Are you assuming your Toeplitz matrix is self-adjoint?

Comment: The Toeplitz matrix considered is Hermitian matrix. Thank you for looking at my question.

Comment: I think you need further conditions to make this interesting. You can take $T1 = T + \gamma I$, $T2 = - \gamma I$, where $\gamma$ is a large constant. This way, $T1$ will have only positive eigenvalues, and $T2$   will have negative ones (since you're shifting them by $\gamma$).

Comment: True. Thank you for your comment. I assumed constant norm  or unchanged diagonal condition need to be apply. Thanks a lot.
